# Why are the Y coordinates of a font glyph's bounding box negative with respect to the ascender/descender?

Tags: fonts, truetype, glyph

I've been working with a TTF font parser, and I'm now working to understand glyph bounding boxes.

Unfortunately, I seem a little confused about the coordinate system.

A version of the following statement appears in most of the documentation I've read:

> **the ascent**: this is the distance from the baseline to the
> highest/upper grid coordinate used to place an outline point. **It is a
> positive value, due to the grid's orientation with the Y axis upwards.**
>
> **the descent**: the distance from the baseline to the lowest grid
> coordinate used to place an outline point. **This is a negative value,
> due to the grid's orientation.**

The values I'm getting from the parser agree with that:

```
ascent: 79.16667
descent: -20.833334
```

But, when I ask the parser for the bounding box of specific glyphs, the ones I expect to be above the baseline, are strictly negative, and those with descenders extend into the positive range:

```
x: { min: { x: 1.7083335, y: -45.083336 }, max: { x: 40.41667, y: 0.0 } }
y: { min: { x: 0.91666675, y: -45.083336 }, max: { x: 39.33334, y: 18.208334 } }
Q: { min: { x: 4.541667, y: -61.5 }, max: { x: 53.58334, y: 10.25 } }
```

I saw another question on here that mentioned when calculating the bounding box you needed to add the x values and subtract the y values, although it didn't explain why.

It's not hard for me to implement what I need to with the signs reversed, I just wanted to make sure I understood the implications, especially since I haven't been able to find any documentation explaining why this is the case.

I'm working in Rust with rusttype, although the aforementioned question was using other tools, so I don't believe that it's relevant.

Comment: Overall bounding box values, across all glyphs, can be read from the [head](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/head) table. For individual glyphs, the bounding box values can be read from the header of an entry in the [glyf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/glyf) table. If you're getting -ve y values when you expect +ve, that's a parsing bug. Note that contours are stored in a compact format using delta vectors and flags, not (x,y) coordinates directly.

Comment: Btw, it might help to show how you are parsing a glyph entry. Then a specific answer can be provided.